# How can I get the current GPS location?

Tags: java, android, gps

I know that this has been asked before but all the solutions available require me to use `onLocationChanged()` method so I can use the `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` methods to get coordinates.

But `onLocationChanged()` will be called when the location of my device is changed. So in order to get my current location I would have to move my device.

But I want to get the current coordinates without having to move my device. Also I read somewhere that I can call the `onLocationChanged()` method manually and I can get the last known location but again. Isn't it possible that the last known location won't be my current location? or is it ok to use the last known location solution?

This is part of a class that I am using to implement LocationListener.

```
public class MyLocListener extends MapsActivity implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if(location!=null)
        {
            MapsActivity.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            MapsActivity.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        }
    }}
```

This is the override of the function I am using to provide coordinates to my map activity. latitude and longitude are two double type variables. In this class the latitude and longitude variables are initiated with 0 and they remain that way since the `onLocationChanged()` function is only called when my location is changed. Hence I can't see my current location on the map.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        LocationManager myLocManager;

        myLocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MyLocListener loc = new MyLocListener();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, loc);

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

Comment: If you search on the web "android current location" you'll find https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: have a look answer for step by step code http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397092/5955362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Should use GooglePlayServices

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
```

To get location

```
 if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

After connection

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
```

For more detail information check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Answer (score 0):

move your code inside location changed. Since getting location is asynchronous,your latitude and longitude never appear reflect. optimize the initializations as needed.

```
public class MyLocListener extends MapsActivity implements LocationListener {

public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if(location!=null)
    {
        MapsActivity.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        MapsActivity.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }
}}
```

Comment: onLocationUpdate starts registering updates from the first call of requestLocations as soon as the provider becomes available. It will keep returning updated locations even if you don't move from time to time